# How can send custom error message after git push from local git server by using jgit api

Tags: java, spring, git, jgit

I have been making a local git server by using jgit .
Following is my code repository for local git server.

https://github.com/masumcse1/mygitserver

https://github.com/masumcse1/mygitserver/blob/main/src/main/java/org/meveo/api/git/MeveoGitServlet.java

git clone http://localhost:9090/mygitserver/git/customer

This program is working for all type basic git command (clone  , push , pull).
Now i want to send  custom error from this servlet after pushing wrong file (other than .java file) from any user .

User will receive this error message from his git client .
any one please explain how can i send this error for git client after push any thing wrong file type.

[image: after pushing git client message is success]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: this idea is correct.